# How can I trade Pokemon between my 3DS and my PC?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, emulation, pokemon-sixth-generation

On one hand I have Sapphire on my PC, running with VBA emulator, and on the other I have Pokemon X on my 3DS. I wanted to trade several Gen 3 and lower Pokemon between them, but couldn't find out how. I tried to connect the 3DS to my PC with a USB cable, but it still didn't help. On the 3DS I found you can switch with wireless connection, but since I dont have another 3DS, I dont see how it helps.

Is there such an option? And if so, how do I do this?

Comment: You can't. You'd have to transfer the Pokemon to Diamond, Pearl, Platinum, SoulSilver or HeartGold, then to Black or White before being able to use PokeTransfer/PokeBank to Pokemon X/Y.

Comment: Can I play SoulSilver on 3DS? And if yes, how can I trade between my Sapphire on the PC and the SoulSilver on my 3DS?

Comment: Pal Park (the means to transfer pokemon from a game such as Ruby) works by inserting the cartridge into the GBA slot of a Nintendo DS and playing the Gen 4 game (in your case, SoulSilver). I haven't heard of any way of doing it wirelessly.

Comment: May someone explain why this question gets downvoted? Sure it's a "common known fact", but it's also an honest question.

Answer (score 2):

No. Let's break this down a little:

- To get Pokemon onto X/Y (Gen6), you need one of B/W/B2/W2 (Gen5)
- To get Pokemon onto B/W/B2/W2 (Gen5), you need two DS units, one of them with a Gen4 game (D/P/Pt/HG/SS).
- To get Pokemon onto D/P/Pt/HG/SS (Gen4), you need a Gen3 (R/S/E/FR/LG) GBA cart inserted into the bottom slot of a DS/DSlite.

At no point along these steps is there a legitimate means to transfer Pokemon from a ROM on your PC to the official game cartridges.

Answer (score 2):

### **They lie!**

**Yes, it was possible until 5th generation and they work on it for the 6th, too.**

**WARNING:** These are non-official tools which aim to be legitimate, but can't prove they really are.

For the 5th generation, there have been tools like *PokéSav* and *PokéGen*. With these tools it was possible to create/edit Pokémons on your PC - no emulation software needed. Then again you were able to uploads these Pokémon files to another website, which gave you another DNS adress (an IP) for your Nintendo (3)DS. If you have edited your Nintendos options to that, started the game and looked into the *GTS*, you were gifted your uploaded Pokémon.

So this can be a possibility that you again create your emulation-Pokémons and transfer them to your gambling device.

**I can not recommend this**, as I can't tell what happens. You can upload legitimate Pokémon, which *may* be undetectet. But you also can create impossibly strong Pokémons which naturally won't occure. I don't know what Nintendo does with such bad, bad people. So be aware.

**I would recommend** you to use *Wondertrade* or the *GTS* of the 6th gen. With *Wondertrade* it's easy to get all starter Pokémons, Evees and so on. In *GTS* you can search for a desired Pokémon (scroll at the end of the alphabet there).

When *Pokémon Bank* opens at last, there will be those missing Pokémons, too, so just be patient for them.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but very, very hard. You need legit copies of Sapphire and everything in between. You also need a flashcart, plus several homebrew tools and a couple DS units and a router. Unless you happen to have all this laying around or want to devote a lot of dollars and hours into this project, it's just not worth it.

Basically, you use the flashcart to transfer the emulated save file to the legit game, and then you ride up the layers to your desired game.

Answer (score 0):

**THIS METHOD IS HARD AND DIFFERENT** *but it does just what you want!*

First on PC trade your pokemon up to gen 4 (Maybe possible with no$gba)

It is possible but, pretty difficult. I haven't done it from PC gen 4 to Gen 6 but, I have done it to gen 4 and I know you could to gen 6. Here is how it goes.

1. Get a DS or DS Lite. (assuming you have a 3ds also)
2. Get an R4 Softmod Chip (Goes in the place you put a DS game. It lets you put unsigned code (backed-up games or home-brew) on a Micro SD card on it)
3. Put a 4th gen Pokemon game on the R4 card (Soul Silver or Heart Gold are easiest)
4. Copy your .SAV file to the same place on the Micro SD card that came with your R4 as your 4th gen Pokemon game.
5. Rename your save so that it matches your games name but with .SAV instead of .NDS
6. Load the game on your R4 card to test that your save worked.
7. Trade your Pokemon up to gen 6 using both DS's
8. You're done.